# Rails: Is there a way to 'rescue' a request using the wrong HTTP verb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, redirect, request

I have a link on my site that sets options for the user and then redirects them back to the page they were on. However Rails always uses a GET to redirect, I've seen workarounds to this but I'd rather have a catch-all for any request that uses the 'wrong' HTTP verb. e.g. if a HTTP verb is used that is not defined in routes then always go to the home page.

thanks!

Comment: If you are on rails > 3 there is no actual solution, but you can do this: http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/36-rails-3-0-rescue-from-routing-error-solution

Answer (score 0):

use match in your routes.rb to catch all request regardless of verb

eg.
in your routes.rb

`match 'photos', to: 'photos#show', via: [:get, :post]`

match requests with get and post verbs to your photos show action

but imo fixing the request url/link verb is not a walkaround but actually the proper way to do it

Comment: Can you clean up and expound upon your current answer?

Comment: As it is, this is really more of a comment than an answer. This is pretty vague, answers shouldn't just be general hints.